# Importing attributes/variations with WooCommerce Product CSV Import Suite

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have imported several products. I now need to import variations of some of these products (i.e. size, color, style). I looked through the documentation, specifically the Attributes and Product Variations sections, but am still lost on how this should be done.

From the [Product Variations](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/product-csv-import-suite/#section-13) section of the documentation, it is my understanding that a separate CSV needs to be imported just for the variations and that I need to use *meta:attribute_pa_size*, *meta:attribute_pa_color*, and *meta:attribute_pa_style* for the column headers.

But then, in the [Attributes](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/user-guide/extensions/product-csv-import-suite/#section-9) section, it says I need to insert these columns: *attribute:attribute name*, *attribute:pa_size*, and *attribute_data:pa_size*

My question is, where do these columns get inserted?

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to see how to build the variation spreadsheet is to create a product with variations and use the csv export option for variations. Once you export the variations, use the same spreadsheet to import your new products.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have figured it out by now, but for others out there I have posted an example using my own attributes.  My variable attribute was size (in Feet and Inches).

1. What Column Header to use in Variable Products CSV
2. What Values to use under that column header
3. What Column Header to use in Variations CSV
4. What Values to use under that column header

a. Variable Products CSV Header (**Two Columns**)

```
attribute:pa_size

attribute_data:pa_size
```

b. Values for Variable CSV Headers

```
2' 6'' x 4' 0''|3' 6'' x 5' 6''|5' 0'' x 8' 0''|8' 0'' x 10' 0'' 

0|0|1 <--*Important* Tells Attribute to be used for Variations
```

c. Values for Variable CSV Headers

```
meta:attribute_pa_size
```

d. Values for Variations CSV Header

```
2' 6'' x 4' 0''
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the meta  **meta** in your  **meta:attribute_pa_size** it should be  **attribute_pa_size** click **Import Variations** and not **Import Products** once you upload and submit it will give you a map fields. Just follow the instruction here: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-importing-product-variations/